# datatable, update footer info totalSize value without redrawing table

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a datatable that gets called in a function like this:

```
function createDatatable(){
    //get table data
    var resp = getTableData()
    var dataset = resp.data //table data
    var total = resp.total  //number like 238

    //if table already exists
    if (myProductGapsTable) {
        myProductGapsTable.clear();
        myProductGapsTable.rows.add(dataset);  //add new dataset
        //myProductGapsTable.language.reload();   //trying to get something like this to work
        myProductGapsTable.draw();
    } else {
     
    //create table
    myProductGapsTable = $('#myProductGapsTable').DataTable({
            scrollY: "60vh", 
            scrollX: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: false,
            fixedColumns: true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            data: dataset,
            retrieve: false,
            "language": { 
                "emptyTable": "No table data availiable.", 
                "info": `Showing _START_ to _END_ of ${total} entries`,
            },
            "sDom": 'ti',
            "paging": false,
            "preDrawCallback": function (settings) {
                pageScrollPos = $("#myProductGapsTableContainer div.dataTables_scrollBody").scrollTop();
            },
            "drawCallback": function (settings) {
                $("#myProductGapsTableContainer div.dataTables_scrollBody").scrollTop(pageScrollPos);
            },
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: 'excel',
                    exportOptions: { rows: { selected: true, search: 'applied' } }

                },
                {
                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
                    text: 'csv',
                    exportOptions: { rows: { selected: true, search: 'applied' } }
                },
            ],
            select: {
                style: 'multi',
                selector: 'td:first-child',
                search: 'applied'
            },
            order: [1, 'asc'],
        });
    }
}
```

I am trying to have the info field use a custom total number for the info footer, this works fine when the table is first created; it will load the number (238 initially) in the footer correctly. But when I call the function again, if the total number is changed (like now lets say total is 77), the footer info text will not show the updated 'out of 77' text that I would like it to have.

I have an if statement that checks if the table has already been created when the function is called, is there any way I can refresh or reload the table's language field? So I can refresh the table's lower dom info text when the if statement is called?

Comment: Just for clarification: Is the value of `resp.total` different from the count of records in `resp.data`? Sounds like it is (or can be). Otherwise, I would expect `"Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries"` to work as needed.

Comment: yes, imagine that the function getTableData() returns an object like {data:[asd,asd,asd], total:787}. By default the _TOTAL_ value does not work because my table is displaying 800,000+ rows of data, so it uses an infinite scrolling type of pagination to gradually load the data. so im trying to give the footer info text a value to use as the total, which will be updated every time the createDatatable() function is called, even if there is a new _TOTAL_ value and the table already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this using the DataTables API, unfortunately, but here is a jQuery/DOM way:

```
function changeCountTotal() {
  total = resp.total;
  var info = $('#myProductGapsTable_info').html();
  // Format is assumed to be: "Showing 1 to 10 of 1,234 entries"
  var regex = /(Showing.*of ).+?( entries)/;
  var updatedinfo = info.replace(regex, "$1" + total + "$2");
  $('#example_info').html(updatedinfo);
}
```

This would need to be called *after* the redraw peformed by `myProductGapsTable.draw();`, to ensure the other parameters (`_START_`, `_END_`) are correctly re-evaluted by DataTables.

If you want to format the total for thousands separators (or whatever is appropriate for your locale), that would be something like this:

```
total = resp.total.toLocaleString()
```

(If there is a way to do this using the DataTables API, that would be a better answer, of course.)

Comment: thank you, I had been evaluating wheather or not to do a direct javascript html dom replacement but wasnt sure how to, but this code is so clean ! that regex expression wow, im going to study this code. thanks

Comment: Glad it helps. The main feature of the regex is its use of two [capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups). The `$1` and `$2` then refer to what was captured by the first `(...)` and second `(...)`, so we can re-use those pieces of text in the final string.